# Using an iterator in python?

Tags: python

I have just learned about iterators in Python however I am having a hard time implementing them.

I am trying to write a class to so that this loop works:

```
  odds = OddNumbers(13)
  for i in odds:
      print(i)
```

I want to write an iter() function and next() function to do this.

So far I have:

```
class OddNumbers:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        current = self.number
        if self.number%2 == 0:
            return current
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

But at the moment this is returning nothing. I expect the output to be

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
```

Help?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have only one element. Why do you need this class to be an iterable?

Comment: What numbers should the example code print?

Comment: If you start with an odd number, then `__next__` will only `raise StopIteration`.  If you start with an even number, it will only return that number.  Did you mean for `__next__` to decrement `self.number` each time?

Comment: @user2357112 Apologies for not putting that in my original post, I forgot! I have edited it in now though.

Comment: In your case,  `__next__` will raise an exception in the first loop, so the iterator stopped, that's why there is nothing print.

Comment: @Brent Washburne I want __next__ to keep on generating the number to return

Comment: As an aside, `max_number` would be a better name for the variable in `OddNumbers`' constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another variable to track the current number:

```
def __init__(self, number):
    self.number = number
    self.current = 1
```

Then you need to compare it with the ending number, and maybe increment it:

```
def __next__(self):
    if self.current > self.number:
        raise StopIteration
    current = self.current
    self.current += 2
    return current
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my issue! At one stage I did have another variable to track the number of iterations, except I didn't initialize it with the __init__ method, I only introduced it in the __next__. Thank you again!

Comment: You shouldn't tell the OP the whole answer, this doesn't teach them anything.

Comment: @augurar, the OP showed effort and posted real code so an answer is the right response.  The comment showed he learned from this.

Comment: @BrentWashburne  You just told him the answer.  So he learned what the correct answer was.  Good job, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Your object needs to keep track of its state and update it when `__next__` is called.

```
class OddNumbers(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.current = ...
        self.number = number

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # Update self.current
        # If the limit has been reached, raise StopIteration
        # Otherwise, return something
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a much cleaner way of doing this, but here is a quick stab:

```
class OddNumbers:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.number
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current > 0:
            if self.current % 2 == 0:
                self.current -= 1
            self.current -= 1
            return self.current + 1
        raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an iterator-like object which provides even or odd numbers. However, it won't satisfy your for loop semantics as it is not a true iterator.

```
class NumberIterator(object):
    """Returns simple even/odd number iterators."""
    def __init__(self, current):
        self.current = current
    def next(self):
        self.current += 2
        return self.current
    @classmethod
    def getOddIterator(cls):
        return cls(-1) # start at 1
    @classmethod
    def getEvenIterator(cls):
        return cls(0) # start at 2


    odd_numbers = NumberIterator.getOddIterator()
    even_numbers = NumberIterator.getEvenIterator()

    odd_numbers.next() # Returns 1
    odd_numbers.next() # Returns 3
```